# Multiple table Update in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am getting error:

> (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'I'.) while executing SQL query.

Please let me know if i am wrong   anywhere.

```
UPDATE tbl_Item I
LEFT JOIN  tbl_Batch B ON  I.Batchuid = B.Batchuid 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_ICLExtCashLetter C ON  B.ICLExtCashLetterUID =  C.ICLExtCashLetteruid
LEFT JOIN  tbl_ICLExtFile F ON F.ICLExtFIleUId = C.ICLExtFileUId
Set MarkICLDone = 0
WHERE F.FileName = @FileName
```

1. tbl_ICLExtFile (PK) = Tbl_ICLExtCashletter (FK) with ID
2. tbl_ICLExtCashletter (PK) = tbl_Batch (FK) with ID
3. tbl_Batch (PK) = tbl_Item(FK) with ID

Comment: this looks meaningless

Comment: 1. There is no | in this script. 2. This script will not run without defining `@Filename`. Post the entire script.

Answer (score 4):

You are using MySQL syntax for update while using SQL Server . 
I am assuming you have already set value of variable  `@FileName` . Syntax for SQL Server multiple table join Update is like below.

```
UPDATE I
Set MarkICLDone = 0
FROM   tbl_Item I     
LEFT JOIN  tbl_Batch B 
   ON  I.Batchuid = B.Batchuid 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_ICLExtCashLetter C 
   ON  B.ICLExtCashLetterUID =  C.ICLExtCashLetteruid
LEFT JOIN  tbl_ICLExtFile F 
   ON F.ICLExtFIleUId = C.ICLExtFileUId

WHERE F.FileName = @FileName
```